# Android how to run gradle task of plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I added a plugin to the root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
...
}
plugins {
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.2.0"
}
```

After doing this I can run gradlew addKtlintCheckGitPreCommitHook in the terminal and the task will run, but I don't see this task in the Gradle-Tab on the right of Android Studio. I also would like to run this task only once. This tasks creates a file in the .git directory, so it's needed only once per project actually.

I tried following:

```
task installGitHook() {
    println("++++++")
    addKtlintCheckGitPreCommitHook
}
```

But this does not run the task, it prints ++++ though.

Answer (score 0):

```
task installGitHook() {
  println("++++++")
  def ktlintCheckTask = project.tasks.getByName('addKtlintCheckGitPreCommitHook')
  ktlintCheckTask.installHook()
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?